# SimpleDateFormat vs DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetimeformatter

I have a use case where I have to compare 2 string dates such as

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("2019-07-07").compareTo(dateFormat.parse("2019-07-07 23:59:59"))>0);
```

The above statement using SimpleDateFormat works perfectly fine, now I try doing it using DateTimeFormatter

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println( LocalDate.parse("2019-07-07", formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse("2019-07-07 23:59:59", formatter))>=0);
```

This fails with exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-07 23:59:59' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at com.amazon.payrollcalculationengineservice.builder.EmployeeJobDataBuilder.main(EmployeeJobDataBuilder.java:226)
```

How can I avoid this using DateTimeFormatter, the Strings which I pass as input can be in any format like yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss , I dont want to write explicitly checks for format , so can I do using DateTimeFormatter as I am able to do this using the SimpleDateFormat library.

Comment: What do you mean by "input can be in any format"? It's only `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, right? Any other formats?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes in these 2 formats I meant.

Comment: Please, just to make you aware if not already. 
You're better of using `DateTimeFormatter` as its thread safe, `SimpleDateFormat` isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[]` to specify an optional part of the pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[ HH:mm:ss]");
```

Alternatively, use the overload of `parse` that takes a `ParsePosition`, which won't try to parse the entire string if not necessary.

```
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
var localDate = LocalDate.from(formatter.parse("2019-07-07 23:59:59", new ParsePosition(0)))
```